# How to set only the maximum Toplevel width?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

Is there a way to set only the maximum width of Toplevel without setting it for the height?

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is one, just leave a `0` value for a `height` parameter:

```
#   import
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Toplevel(root)

#   check-print maxsize
print(top.maxsize())

#   change only width to 300
top.maxsize(width=300, height=0)

#   check-print maxsize again
print(top.maxsize())

#   show only Toplevel and handle closing
top.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', root.destroy)
root.withdraw()

root.mainloop()
```